# Why is my vue v-for div not rendering and not throwing any errors?

Tags: vue.js, v-for

I have a vue componenet where I want to render out a multidimensional array, but when I set up the v-for the div doesn't render at all and doesn't throw any errors. I put a console.log output in the computed method and that returns the multidimensional array that I am trying to display on the page, but the v-for won't render it. Also, right before the v-for I try to render an item from the array and it works fine, it just doesn't render the v-for div. Do y'all know why it isn't rendering?

Here is the template

```
<div>
    this is a test
    {{ assets['Article'][0].assetTitle }}
    <div class="assets" v-for="(assetArray, assetCategory) in assets" v-bind:key="assetCategory">
      test
      <h4>{{ assetCategory }}</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is my computed:

```
computed: {
      ...mapGetters([
         'getAssetSubArrays'
      ]),
      assets () {
          let test = this.$store.getters.getAssetSubArrays(this.flyoutLayer)
          console.log(test)
          console.log('test')
          return test
      }
  },
```

And here is the array returned by console.log(test)
[image]

Comment: Is that an array with non-numeric properties? You may need to change it to a normal object, so `{}` instead of `[]`.

Comment: Is `getAssetSubArrays` asynchronous?

Answer (score 1):

@skirtle gave the right answer in the comments. I had initiated the array as an array = [], and as soon as I switched it to array = {} it worked. Thanks Skirtle!

Comment: Were you doing SSR?